# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion seed() doesn't create tables in database

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In my MVC project I want to use automatic migrations and automatic update-database.

I have an AppActivator class - where I initialize the DB:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "PreStart")]
[assembly: PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "PostStart")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "Stop")]

namespace Manual.Web
{
    public static class AppActivator
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ManualContext, Configuration>());

            MeasurementConfig.RegisterUnits();
            MiniProfilerPreStart();    
        }
 ...
}
```

And the configuration class - where I call the seed function:

```
    public  class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ManualContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ManualContext context)
        {
            //if (context.Items != null && context.Items.Count() == 0)
            try
            { 
                ManualDbInitializerSeed.SeedForDB(context); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            }

        }
    }
```

And the seed function:

```
public static void SeedForDB(ManualContext context)
        {
            foreach (MI_Item s in RegisterItemsConfig.GetConfig().Items)
            {
                Item st = new Item { Key = s.Name, DefaultUnknownItem = s.DefaultUnknown };
                context.Items.Add(st);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
...
}
```

But on save changes - I get this error:

```
"Invalid object name 'dbo.Items'." {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

And when I look in SQL management studio I see that there is a new DB "Manual" but it has only migration table and doesn't have the rest of the tables.

If I use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists it works fine - but it does not support migrations so it's not a good solution for me.

I don't want to write all the code in SQL because I lose all the advantage of code-first.

Comment: This weird answer really helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048844/1025142